# 'NSPersistentCloudKitContainer' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit

So i added CloudKit To my project and i changed my NSPersistentContainer to NSPersistentCloudKitContainer but it says 'NSPersistentCloudKitContainer' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

How Do i Fix This

[image]

I tried to update my target to 13.0, but it still doesnt work:

[image]

I also Updated my Simulator To 13.0 but it still doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How Do You Fix This?

Comment: set your project target to ios13.

Comment: Umm I did, but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Any Way to Fix It?

Comment: that should do it. try to clean the build folder?

Comment: doesn't work still, what do you think could be the problem

Comment: it's confused. try changing it back to 12, build, then back to 13 and build again. it's not the simulator for sure. make sure that the debug target is also 13, there are different targets for debug and deploy.

Comment: Do I remove NSPersistentCloudKitContainer?

Comment: How to Change Debug Target

Comment: select the target, then build settings, then basic. top section

Comment: Tysm, it worked like a charm :), mind posting your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that all targets are set to ios13.

Select the target, then build settings, then basic. top section